# Android web view Ajax request data not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have wep application which some pages have to do ajax requests to get and update that pages.

My problem when I use android WebView to load that wep application. all pages that request ajax doesn't update the page with requested data which means the ajax requests don't work.

here is the code of MainActivity.java
Plaese Some one HELP ME!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "onPageStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "onPageFinished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        //webSettings.getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs();
        //webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   /* class JsObject {
        public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
    }
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");*/
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.200/connection3/index.html");
    }
}
```